# ruby on rails: request.body.read shows error

Tags: ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload

I have implemented AJAX based upload in my rails project.

This is my example code. (I followed the tutorial from here.. https://github.com/valums/file-uploader)

```
********** Javascript Code **********

function createUploader(){
    var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
        element: document.getElementById('file-uploader'),
        action: '/product/upload',        
    });
}

window.onload = createUploader;

********** Server side **********
def upload
  @filename = params['qqfile']

  f = File.open('home/files/' + @filename, "wb")
  str =  request.body.read
  f.write(str)
  f.close

  render :text => '{success:true}'
end
```

When i run my code i got the following error message in the line "str =  request.body.read"

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `body' for #<ActionController::CgiRequest:0xb6cd71a0>):
```

error details More: http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/01NE

My configuration:

```
[mrblack@ home]# ruby -v  
ruby 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [i686-linux]  
[mrblack@ home]# rails -v  
Rails 1.2.1  
[mrblack@ home]# gem -v  
1.8.6
```

Can you please clear me, what did i wrong?

Comment: it looks like the line `str = request.body.read` is the faulty line here, and that the `request` object doesn't have a 'body' method.

Comment: Also, why in the world are you using rails 1.2.1? That version is _really_ old.

Comment: OH!!!.. I'll review about it, thanks. Bcz, my project is 7 yrs old. That's why i can't update. :-)

Comment: Ah, I see... seven years old rails code... Uuuh, scary ;)

Answer (score 1):

Becasue in Rails 1.2.1 neither ActionController::CgiRequest nor its parent ActionController::AbstractRequest contains 'body' method. You can see it if you look at these pages: [cgi_process.rb](http://www.railsbrain.com/api/rails-1.2.1/doc/index.html?a=F00000052&name=cgi_process.rb) and [request.rb](http://www.railsbrain.com/api/rails-1.2.1/doc/index.html?a=C00000188&name=AbstractRequest#). Why do you use such old rails version??

**UPDATE**
@Mr. Black. You wrote "Can you please tell me any alternate way to read the incoming request similar to this request object".
You're using 'file-uploader' library from github. As I can see, that library can upload files to server side by two ways. If user has old FF, Chrome browsers or any IE version that library make a post request to iframe. If user has modern FF or Chrome version library prepares async post xmlHttpRequest. Therefore, in our rails controller we have to handle both situation. For example, for simplicity we want to write sended file data to some hard-coded place on disk.

```
******** app/controllers/greetings_controller.rb ********
class GreetingsController < ApplicationController
  def upload
    begin
      is_xhr = params[:qqfile].is_a? String
      data = is_xhr ? request.body : params[:qqfile]
      File.open("/some_place_on_disk/bar.txt", "w") { |f| f.write(data.read) }
      @result = {success: true}
      if is_xhr
        render :json => @result
      end
      # else render view
    rescue Exception => e
      logger.info e
      @result = {error: "Error has been encountered during the processing"}
    end
  end
end

******** app/views/upload.html.erb ********
<%= @result.to_json %>


******** config/routes.rb ********
.....
match '/upload' => 'greetings#upload', :via => :post
.....
```

You can use demo.htm from github project, but you have to place it into public folder. Don't forget about fileuploader.css and fileuploader.js! :) You must change 'action' in createUploader function to action path, in my case that would be '/upload'

Comment: Ah!! Yeah..Thanks @WarHog. Can you please tell me any alternate way to read the incoming request similar to this request object?.

Comment: I've updated previous post and wrote some example. Good luck!